# Know in JwtBearerEvents if [AllowAnonymous] was used

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I have two JWTs that I deal with.  One for the user and one for the application.

I have logic for one of those JWTs to be set as the "token".  This is done in `JwtBearerEvents`'s `OnMessageReceived` method.

It looks like this:

```
OnMessageReceived = context =>
{
    var headers = context.Request.Headers;
    context.Token = headers[primaryJwtHeaderKey];
                
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

This works great except for `[AllowAnonymous]`.  `[AllowAnonymous]` still takes on the logic of `AuthorizationOptions.FallbackPolicy`, but makes it non-binding.

But this means that when it runs through the method above, I have no way of knowing if the call is an `[AllowAnonymous]` call or actually is my fallback policy.

I need to know so that when an `[AllowAnonymous]` call comes through, I choose one of the JWTs if the other is empty.  (Meaning if there was no user JWT then I set the token to be the application JWT.)  But I should only do this if the call is an anonymous call.  (Otherwise I could be allowing a call through that should be blocked.)

**Is there someway to know if a call is `[AllowAnonymous]` from within the `JwtBearerOptions.JwtBearerEvents.OnMessageReceived` event?**

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What is the issue that happens when an anonymously accessible endpoint is called?

Comment: @juunas - Even though it is anonymous, there may still be tokens provided that could be useful to the service operation.  If it is anonymously accessed, then I want to try to provide any one of the tokens I can find in the headers (I have 2 possible, one for the user and one for the application).  I want to do this to provide the service operation with any data in the token.  However, it is not anonymous, then the fallback requires a specific token (the user token).  I have to ensure I don't select the the token application if the call is using the fallback policy (that needs the user token).

Comment: @juunas - so the logic would be: `If (userToken.NotPresent() && isAnonymous) then { SelectApplicationToken()}`  But I don't know how to find out the `isAnonymous` part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the metadata on the endpoint for [`IAllowAnonymous`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authorization.iallowanonymous?view=aspnetcore-5.0) or `AllowAnonymousAttribute`:

```
opt.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
{
    OnMessageReceived = ctx =>
    {
        // This will be null if not anonymous, otherwise, it will be
        // the metadata instance such as AllowAnonymousAttribute
        var allowAnonymous = ctx.HttpContext.GetEndpoint()
            .Metadata.GetMetadata<IAllowAnonymous>();
    }
};
```

If you're also using MVC filters, might also check [`IAllowAnonymousFilter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.authorization.iallowanonymousfilter?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

Answer (score 0):

If the method came through anonymously, than there won't be an identity name associated to the HttpContext.

```
OnMessageReceived = context =>
{
    if (context.HttpContext.User?.Identity.?Name == null) {
        ...
    }
}
```

You could also try:

`context.HttpContext.User?.Identity?.IsAuthenticated`

Comment: Thank you for the response.  Unfortunately, `OnMessageReceived` is called before the `User` object is setup.  (I checked, and the `Name` property was `null` even for an authenticated call.)